Can an index on a property be passed into a MarkLogic UDF?
I have a User Defined Function I've written for MarkLogic that I'd like to do work over three path range indexes. The first two indexes are on element values and the third is over a document property. The path range indexes are all defined and I can confirm that querying them separately returns data for the documents returned in the document query. However, when I pass them into my aggregate function, the tuple that gets passed to the map function is empty. Do UDFs just not work with path range indexes over properties?
cts:aggregate('plugins/ssplugin', 'my_plugin', 
  (cts:path-reference('/path-range-index-1'), 
   cts:path-reference('/path-range-index-2'), 
   cts:path-reference('/prop:properties/path-range-index-3')
  ), $args, (), cts:document-query('/uri/to/data/that/works/for/aggregate'))


Try specifying "any" in the options. If you apply a query, and don't specify an option indicating what you are targeting, it assumes the document fragment, and won't look at the properties fragment.
The behavior is mentioned in the Usage Notes:

Only one of "any", "document", "properties", or "locks" may be specified in the options parameter. If none of "any", "document", "properties", or "locks" are specified and there is a $query parameter, then the default is "document". If there is no $query parameter then the default is "any".


Adding "any" to the options got the same empty result. The docs for the query parameter of cts:aggregate does also state "Only include co-occurrences in fragments selected by the cts:query". So does my query also need to include both the document and properties in what it returns? In my actual query I was only actually querying for a specific uri.
